# Why doesn't LOAD DATA INFILE do anything? It doesn't show any errors but doesn't add anything

Tags: php, mysql, database, csv

```
$filename = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '1.csv';

$query = "LOAD DATA INFILE '$filename'
     INTO TABLE tablename
     FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|'
     (name, description);";

$conn->query($query);
```

Comment: It doesn't look like you're checking for any errors. MySQL queries do not throw errors like PHP does without additional configuration. You need to explicitly check for errors via the mysql API you're using.

Comment: ... or execute the query obtained in `$query` (dumped value) in CLI and look for error.

Comment: Please use echo "Error : " . $conn -> error; to display error after $conn->query($query); statement to show the error in query execution.

Comment: I don't see a line terminator in your load statement, Please add your table definition and a few lines of your csv file.

Comment: It's not necessary to specify the line terminator in LOAD DATA INFILE. If you don't specify one, it will use a default of `\n`.